# Lt. Columbo's "It didn't take me until July"

Tags: expressions

Heard the following exchange in the *Columbo* episode [*An Exercise in Fatality*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Columbo#An_Exercise_in_Fatality_[4.1]):

> Lt. Columbo: You removed the bulb on the phone in the living room so
>   the line wouldn't light up (...).
>
> Milo Janus: Guesswork, supposition, more cigar ashes. What you need is
>   proof. That what you need -- proof.
>
> Lt. Columbo: **It didn't take me 'til July**, but I got the proof.

Never heard this exact expression before - and a cursory Google search did not yield any useful hits re. its origin or contemporary usage.

What's the origin of the expression - and is it something that a contemporary US English speaker would easily understand?

Can we use something other than "*July*" (another month of the year, day of the week etc.) to convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a call back to an earlier quote within the episode, and thus only makes sense within the context of the episode -

> Milo Janus: I don't care what you think. I don't care what you suspect. I don't care what visions you see when you look at your cigar ashes because I'm innocent. I have an alibi for the time Gene Stafford died and you can huff and puff on that rotten cigar until next July and you'll never prove otherwise.
>
> Lt. Columbo: I wouldn't count on that.